# External Monitor not displaying BIOS screen

Tags: display, bios, external

My Sony Vaio laptop screen has stopped functioning, so I am using an external monitor for display. I want to re-install Windows, but I cannot enter the BIOS screen because after pressing the Assist button the external display remains blank. For normal boot the external display works fine. Is there any way to make the external monitor come on to display the BIOS setup? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BIOS (not dependent on the OS) goes to the Laptop screen. This is built in.

So, no, there is not a way to make the laptop BIOS boot to the external screen.

You might try a dock that makes the screen look like native. I recall doing this with Lenovo machines (big multipin connector on the bottom that connects with the dock and makes it part of the laptop).

Otherwise, you need to repair the screen.

Comment: There might be an option in BIOS to make an external monitor the default.  However, you would have to get in to BIOS to change the option, if its there.